# svg transform on element not working in Edge

Tags: svg, microsoft-edge, svg-transforms

This fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1tq8gkha/1/ shows the problem

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 14 10" width="20px" 
     transform="rotate(270)" >

     <path fill="currentColor" d="M 9.21136 7.59931 l 4.48338 -4.86723 c 0.407008 -0.441854 0.407008 -1.15825 0 -1.60046 l -0.73712 -0.80023 c -0.407008 -0.441854 -1.0669 -0.441854 -1.47424 0 L 7 5.19862 L 2.51662 0.33139 c -0.407008 -0.441853 -1.0669 -0.441853 -1.47424 0 l -0.737121 0.80023 c -0.407008 0.441854 -0.407008 1.15825 0 1.60046 l 4.48338 4.86723 L 7 10 l 2.21136 -2.40069 Z" />
</svg>
```

If viewed in Chrome or Firefox the chevron is correctly rotated to point right.
In Edge the transform is not applied and it points down.

I have seen several references to Edge not applying CSS transforms, but all other references suggest that using transform on the element does work in Edge.

Is there a trick to this, or does Edge just not support it?

Comment: In SVG 1.1, only these 16 elements were allowed to use the transform attribute, without the svg element. You could check the allowed elements from [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform), it contains the path element. So, as a workaround, I suggest you could add the transform attribute on the path element, please check [this sample](https://jsfiddle.net/yg2jqc9a/).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the list.  I had tried adding the transform to the path and it still didn't work, but I did this in my code not on the fiddle, so there must be something else interfering. thanks.

Comment: OK, for completeness when rotating on the element a height is required.  Also, `transform-origin="center"` is required

Comment: Congratulation, it seems that you have already found the solution, cheers. In [my sample](https://jsfiddle.net/yg2jqc9a/), I also change the value of the viewbox attribute and the width and height attribute, like this `viewBox="0 0 42 10" width="200px" height="200px"`, so it looks well in Edge browser.